# How to get multidimensional array to single array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have following array which contain array name, email, phone, address

```
$result=Array( [name] => Array( [0] => Xyz1 [1] => xyz2 ) [email] => Array ( [0] => xyz1@gmail.com [1] => xyz2@gmail.com ) [phone] => Array ( [0] => 23423423-1 [1] => 23423423-2 ) [address] => Array ( [0] => xyz1 [1] => xyz2 ));
```

and i want this to single array like below

```
$r1=Array ( [name] => xyz1 [email] => xyz1@gmail.com [phone] => 23423423-1 [address] => xyz1 );  
$r2=Array ( [name] => xyz2 [email] => xyz2@gmail.com [phone] => 23423423-2 [address] => xyz2 );
```

Comment: What you have tried so far..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the keys correspond to each other by their indexes, i.e. the 1st email value corresponds to the 1st name value etc, you can loop through the indexes and keys to generate your new array:

```
foreach(array_keys($result['name']) as $i) {

    $row = array();

    foreach(array_keys($result) as $key) {
        $row[$key] = $result[$key][$i];
    }

    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, This is exactly which i want

Answer (score 1):

In your given array, keys will be same and all of them contains bunch of data, **may have varying number of entries**. You can use **array_keys** for fetching all keys and get their relevant data and store them in relevant keys, i.e. name on key 0 will be in final results 0 key and so on.
Try this code:

```html
<?php
    $r = array();
 $keys = array_keys($result); //name,email, etc...

 foreach ($keys as $value)
 {
   foreach ($result[$value] as $k => $v)
   {
    $r[$k][$value] = $v;
   }
 } 
 print_r($r);
?>
```

**Result**

```html
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [name] => Xyz1 [email] => xyz1@gmail.com [phone] => 23423423-1 [address] => xyz1 ) 

[1] => Array ( [name] => xyz2 [email] => xyz2@gmail.com [phone] => 23423423-2 [address] => xyz2 ) 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
for($i=0; $i<=count($result['name']); $i++){
    $r[]=array('name'=>$result['name'][$i],'email'=>$result['email'][$i],'phone'=>$result['phone'][$i],'address'=>$result['address'][$i]);
}
```

You can access your first record using $r[0] eg $r[0]['name']